# WPF DATAGRID - How to binding two tables fields in xaml

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

Please help.

I have two relational tables which are Employee and EmployeePosition. I am trying to bind two tables into one datagrid on the xmal file **without using LINQ** to join those two table into one collection from the c# code behind. HOW CAN I DO IT?
The sample code and table below

**Empolyee**
EmployeeID
FirstName
LastName
PositionID

**EmployeePosition**
PositionID
Title

My excepted result is:

```
EmployeeID   FirstName   LastName  Title
```

**Xaml file**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid">
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}"/>            
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding Title}"/>
</DataGrid>
```

**The C# Code**

```
var employee = from e in _db.Employees
               select e;
this.DataGrid.ItemsSource = employee;
```

Please help
Patrick

Comment: Which persistence layer are you using (LINQ-to-SQL, Entity Framework, etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

Are u using Linq-2-SQL? Linq-2-Entities?

Whatsoever, you should have a navigation property `EmployeePosition` in the `Employee` type.
Make sure that when it's eagerly-loaded (hard to tell you about since I don't know what Linq you use), the `PropertyChanged` event of the `Employee` (which should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`) is raised with that property name.

Then you can simply bind it in the xaml: `Binding="{Binding EmployeePosition.Position}"`