# Datagrid Binding with two tables

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid

Please help.

I have two relational tables which are Employee and EmployeePosition. I am trying to bind two tables into one datagrid on the xmal file **without using LINQ** to join those two table into one collection from the c# code behind. HOW CAN I DO IT?
The sample code and table below

**Empolyee**
EmployeeID
FirstName
LastName
PositionID

**EmployeePosition**
PositionID
Title

My excepted result is:

```
EmployeeID   FirstName   LastName  Title
```

**Xaml file**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid">
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}"/>            
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding Title}"/>
</DataGrid>
```

**The C# Code**

```
var employee = from e in _db.Employees
               select e;
this.DataGrid.ItemsSource = employee;
```

Please help
Patrick

Comment: Having your question title all in caps will only discourage people from answering your question. Sprinkling "please help" messages in your question text will only confirm that you are someone who should be ignored.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF DATAGRID - How to binding two tables fields in xaml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318593/wpf-datagrid-how-to-binding-two-tables-fields-in-xaml)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to create a datatable based on a query that selects values from both tables like:

```
SELECT
    Employee.EmployeeID,
    Employee.FirstName,
    EmployeePosition.Title
FROM
    Employee
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    EmployeePosition
ON
    Employee.PositionID = EmployeePosition.PositionID
```

If you are using the dataset designer, you can add a new table adapter from the toolbox:

[image: DataSet Toolbox]

It may take a moment but the table adapter configuration wizard will appear. Select your database and follow the steps until you can add a query:

[image: Enter a query...]

And then follow the rest of the steps in the wizard.

You'll then have a datatable you can use to bind to your datagrid.

Comment: Thank you free-dom

But i would like to binding the Title field on xmal file without join the table behind the code.


Patrick

Comment: Unfortunately, the DataGrid can only have one DataSource object, so at some level there will have to be some object that joins the two together.

If you don't want to create a new DataTable that brings the two together, then you can provide a proxy class that gets the data you are looking for instead, and bind to it instead.